# Deleting large site collection with size 100GB using gradual delete option

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, delete

we have a SharePoint site collection with size of 100GB. We wanted to delete the site permanently and need to use the same site url.

Recommended option is to use gradual delete option in Remove-SPSite cmdlet, to reduce the performance impact on SQL server.

I need to use the same site url immediately without waiting for SharePoint Gradual delete timer job to delete data in a scheduled manner (upto 30 days) , so planning to run the timer job 'Gradual delete' manually .

My question is, will this manual run of 'Gradual Delete' timer job causes the same sql performance impact as like running 'Remove-SPSite' operation without gradual delete option.

If we have the same performance impact on SQL, how can we approach for this large site deletion ?

Comment: Is this site collection in a dedicated content database?

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MVP, no ..this site is part of a content database which hosts other site collections as well.

Comment: how many site collections in that database and whats the size? may be another approach is good if the number of sites and size of sites are small

Comment: @Waqas, the content database is hosting another site with site collection size reaching 100GB.  This is with reference to our earlier [question] (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230510/how-to-separate-the-site-collections-with-large-size-of-100gb-from-large-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to run the gradual delete timer job manually. The function of the job is delete the data from content db without hurting server performance.

Actually when you run remove-spsite then it did not delete site rather delete all connections to the url and put the data in sitedelete table of content db. When you run gradual delete then it remove data from sitedelete table( 1000 rows at a time, I think). Please read this for more details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/08/02/gradual-site-delete-in-sharepoint-2010/

I would make sure before running gradual delete that site not in central admin bin....by running get-spdeletedsite command.

Lastly, I would recommend put each site collection into own content database as they are too big, it will be help you in managing and troubleshooting and maintenance.

Comment: thanks a lot . Could you pls also let me know if any action required related to SQL resources management while doing these tasks . SQL is configured with logshipping jobs to regular data backup to secondary DB server (DR).

Comment: Just keep an eye on it, nothing special required as I mentioned this job is meant for better performance....you need to shrink the database after deletion of site collection so that unused space go back to server and after that reindex.